# How to get rid of this warning consider registering a custom JavaTypeDescriptor or at least implementing equals/hashCode?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am getting the following warning,

> Encountered Java type [class java.lang.Object] for which we could not
> locate a JavaTypeDescriptor and which does not appear to implement
> equals and/or hashCode.  This can lead to significant performance
> problems when performing equality/dirty checking involving this Java
> type. Consider registering a custom JavaTypeDescriptor or at least
> implementing equals/hashCode.

I am implementing an application using Spring Boot with Spring Data JPA. I have a class as follows,

```
public abstract class SomeClass implements Serializable {

   @Convert(converter = SomeConverter.class)
   private Object someEntity;
}
```

I had to use the `Object someEntity` because there are multiple classes eligible for that `someEntity` so I had to use the type as `Object`. And all the eligible `someEntity` classes are also extended a superclass but it is an abstract class, so cannot put it here.

Since that warning is there I created a `JavaTypeDescriptor` as follows,

```
public class ObjectJavaTypeDescriptor implements JavaTypeDescriptor<Object> {

    @Override
    public boolean areEqual(Object one, Object another) {
        return one == another || (one != null && one.equals(another));
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Object> getJavaTypeClass() {
        return Object.class;
    }

    @Override
    public int extractHashCode(Object value) {
        return value.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(Object value) {
        return value.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Object fromString(String string) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
    @Override
    public <X> X unwrap(Object value, Class<X> type, WrapperOptions options) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (Object.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
            return (X) value;
        }
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported");
    }

    @Override
    public <X> Object wrap(X value, WrapperOptions options) {
        return value;
    }
}
```

And I tried the following 2 methods to register this TypeDescriptor,

```
@Bean
public HibernatePropertiesCustomizer hibernatePropertiesCustomizer() {
    return hibernateProperties -> hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.type_descriptors.object",
            "com.example.ObjectJavaTypeDescriptor");
}
```

and this property,

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.type_descriptors.object=com.example.ObjectJavaTypeDescriptor
```

But still, the warning is showing, and I see the application is little bit stuck at the starting and also taking some more time to start. How to resolve this issue? Anybody can help me? Thank you.

Comment: As the error message says. You should implement the equals and the hashCode method

Comment: @Jens In which class because all the eligible classes are already override the equals and the hashcode?